# Android Calendar : Changing the start day of week to Saturday

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have code to get the start date of week with current day as Sunday. But I want to start my week from Saturday-Friday.
How can I achieve this through android?

Comment: Its better to use Joda library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return date of last saturday and set it as a start of the date.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int i = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - cal.getFirstDayOfWeek();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -i - 7);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.Saturday);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.Saturday);
```

i think its help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I have used the same code and its not working, it returns the current date instead of returning the date for last saturday for current week.